# функция активации catboost

Tags: r, catboost

Есть ли возможность в явном виду указать фукнцию активации для catboost.train при использовании её в R ?
К примеру в библиотеке xgboost это делается путем передачи параметра:
"objective = "binary:logistic""

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

У катбуста нет функций активации, это не нейросеть. А параметр, который Вы привели, не есть ф-я активация а объективная функция используемая при оптимизации модели.